# ee.Dictionary.set('var', null)

Tags: google-earth-engine, dictionary

How can one set google earth engine dictionary value to null?
The code `ee.Dictionary.set('var', null)` results in the error  `Dictionary.set: Parameter 'value' is required.`

I am mapping through an image collection and in some images the property I am setting is `null`, but i still need them, so I don't want to filter metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `ee.Algorithms.If` to check if the value is `null` and if so, codify `null` as something else like a string: 'null'.

Here is a demonstration:

```js
var dic = ee.Dictionary({'var': 0});

var value1 = null;
var test1 = ee.Algorithms.If({
  condition: value1,
  trueCase: dic.set('var', value1),
  falseCase: dic.set('var', 'null')});
print('null', test1) ;
  
var value2 = ee.Number(1);
var test2 = ee.Algorithms.If({
  condition: value2,
  trueCase: dic.set('var', value2),
  falseCase: dic.set('var', 'null')});
print('not null', test2);
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i did

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot set to null, you construct a dictionary with null values:

```
var dict = ee.Dictionary({var: null})
print(dict.get('var'))
```

I would be a bit careful with relying on null values in practice though. I've noticed some operations that strip out the keys with null values. Unfortunately, I cannot recall the cases where this happen.